# Kotlin function argument accepting 2/more types

Tags: kotlin

How do you create a function that accepts 2 or more types as an argument in Kotlin? Like, how can you create a GCD function that accepts all integer types?

This function would take in 2 parameters of any numeric type, and return a numeric answer.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Do you mean a function that accepts a variable number of arguments of the same type?  Or a function that accepts a single argument but that argument can be one of multiple types (e.g., union types)?

Comment: Edited, can you confirm I have kept your intended meaning

Answer (score 0):

## Can you take in multiple non-inheriting types

No, this is not supported, if you used Any you would not be able to call methods of Int and Long, even if they both have methods with the same signature.

## Can you take in any Number

You can accept Numbers, then use the toLong method to work on them as numbers.

Comment: Oh, I can't take any number. I can only take integer (non-inheriting) types. So can I define one function for each type?

Comment: You can use number (it's a superclass of all number types) and then call toLong, but this wouldn't stop users passing in doubles, which also extend number